# The following code giving java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main Exception in thread "main" in Eclipse

Tags: java

```
package Demo;

public class CurrentDirectoryExample {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String current = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        System.out.println("Current working directory in Java : " + current);

    }
}
```

Comment: It works here. How are you running it? And why is your package name capitalized?

Comment: Please paste the stack trace.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is bit strange exception as the actual problem differs with the displayed error. You should check whether the project(the program is running in) having any build errors. If any such error exists like refered lib is not available etc, the program will not run.

Concentrate on project for any build errors.

Comment: @downvoter, care for the comment. BTW, create a project in eclipse and run the project with build errors. You will be stumped with exception though the program looks pretty good!